# There are Argentina's friends?I want to buy BTC with Pesos

Tags: argentina

I want to try using the ARS to buy BTC in Argentina and selling the BTC for RMB in China, so as to ecnomic losses from the traditional way of International remittance.Is the method feasible?I am in China and want to know about some information related to the deal.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Related questions have been asked a number of times. In short: If you're in China there are several exchanges willing to buy/sell bitcoins in exchange of yuans, like btcchina.com or okcoin.com . Once you're in Argentina you can locate people willing to trade in person for you via localbitcions.com - you'll find **a lot** of Argentinians willing to trade.